# Rails routing error: uninitialized constant in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rather than use scaffolding I used separate generators for my model, controller and view. so I think I may have one or more of my class or file names wrong. Here is what I have:

model: a/m/smarter_measure.rb

```
class SmarterMeasure< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :life_factors_score, :life_factors_readiness, :personal_attributes_score,
      :personal_attributes_readiness, :tech_comp_score, :tech_comp_readiness, :tech_knowledge_score,
      :tech_knowledge_readiness, :date_completed

end
```

controller:a/c/smarter_measures_controller.rb

```
class SmarterMeasuresController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @results = SmarterMeasure.all
  end
end
```

view:a/v/s/index.html.erb

```
<% @results.each do |r| %>

<% end %>
```

routes:

```
  resources :smartermeasures
```

When I browse to /smartermeasures I get:

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant SmartermeasuresController

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using CamelCase in Model and Controller Classes, you need to name the files and routes with "_" (underlines), meaning:

```
resources :smarter_measures
```

Answer (score 3):

try changing your route to:

```
 resources :smarter_measures
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are right but if you want to stick to the route smartermeasures/ you need to specify the controller in the route file

```
resources :smartermeasures, controller: 'SmarterMeasures'
```